# (python-telegram-bot) AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, attributeerror, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to multi replying with a 'command' as bot from user replied message and got this error

**ERROR**

```
 mesg = update.message.text.split('\n')
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message'
```

**CODE**

```
def _func(bot, update, multi=0):
    mesg = update.message.text.split('\n')
    message_args = mesg[0].split(' ', maxsplit=1)


    if multi > 1:
        time.sleep(4)
        nextmsg = type('nextmsg', (object, ), {'message': update.message, 'chat_id': message.chat_id, 'message_id': message.reply_to_message.message_id + 1})
        msg = message_args[0]
        if len(mesg) > 2:
            msg += '\n' + mesg[1] + '\n' + mesg[2]
        nextmsg = sendMessage(msg, bot, nextmsg)
        nextmsg.from_user.id = update.message.from_user.id
        multi -= 1
        time.sleep(4)
        _func(bot, nextmsg, multi)


def mycommand(update, context):
    _func(context.bot, update)

mycommand_handler = CommandHandler(BotCommands.MyCommandCommand, mycommand,
                                filters=CustomFilters.authorized_chat | CustomFilters.authorized_user, run_async=True)

dispatcher.add_handler(mycommand__handler)
```

**ALSO Importing sendMessage function from another file & the CODE of the sendMessage is down**

```
def sendMessage(text: str, bot, update: Update):
    try:
        return bot.send_message(update.message.chat_id,
                            reply_to_message_id=update.message.message_id,
                            text=text, allow_sending_without_reply=True, parse_mode='HTMl', disable_web_page_preview=True)
    except RetryAfter as r:
        LOGGER.warning(str(r))
        time.sleep(r.retry_after * 1.5)
        return sendMessage(text, bot, update)
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.error(str(e))
```

*How to fix this and send "mycommand" as bot one by one as message to bot by tagging after user first tagged message*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Shouldn't that be ```def sendMessage2(...)```?

Comment: Also,  since ```sendMessage(text, bot, update)``` returns a Message type,  I suspect ```nextmsg``` is a Message type, and ergo ``` _func(bot, nextmsg, multi)``` will have a ```Message``` type in the 2nd parameter.  From the definition of ```_func``` , it should just be ```mesg = update.text.split('\n')```

Comment: You also mention in ```_func```, ```message.chat_id``` and ```message.reply_to_message.message_id + 1``` but ```message``` isn't defined (as given by your code).

Comment: @ewong where and how i define ```message``` in my code above (bcoz newbie!)& i don't want to change ```_func``` parameters bcoz i need them for other things. Also ```sendMessage2``` is typo btw fixed the post now